# Регулярное выражени по извлечению номеров домов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, re

Как написать регулярное выражение, которое из данных строк:

```
д. 1

дом 89

Д 39/2

Дом 30A
```

будет извлекать соответственно:

```
1

89

39/2

30A
```

Comment: Если у вас были попытки самостоятельного решения задачи, то для увеличения вероятности качественного ответа добавьте их, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: `\b\d+(?:\/\d+|[А-Я])?\b`  что нибудь такое попробуйте

Comment: Погодите секунду, `re` - это библиотека на Python, почему вас устроило решение на JavaScript?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Так вопрос был про регулярное выражение в данном случае оно совместимо и с библиотекой python и c библиотекой js. Только js тут встраиваемый и поэтому проще на нем пример привести.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вот вариант можно предложить... Реализация на JS.

```js
const re = /\S+(?=$)/
console.log('д. 1'.match(re)[0])
console.log('дом 89'.match(re)[0])
console.log('Д 39/2'.match(re)[0])
console.log('Дом 30A'.match(re)[0])
```

Comment: Позитивный просмотр вперёд на конец строки`(?=$)`, вместо него можно просто указать конец строки `$`